# OAEPwithMD5andMGF1Padding in node-rsa

Tags: encryption, rsa

I am trying to figure out how to do RSA encryption with OAEPwithMD5andMGF1Padding in node-rsa.

Below is my code in node.js.

```
    var NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var publicKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n*****\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
    var privateKey = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n*****\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
    const constants = require('constants');
    var options1 = {
      environment: 'node',
      encryptionScheme: {
        scheme: 'pkcs1_oaep',
        hash: 'md5', //hash using for scheme
      }
    }
    var text = 'This is the string to be encrypted using RSA!';
    var encryptKey = new NodeRSA(publicKey, 'pkcs8-public', options1);
    encryptKey.setOptions(options1)

    var encrypted = encryptKey.encrypt(text, 'base64');
    console.log(encrypted);
    console.log(encryptKey.isPublic(true))

    var options2  = {
      environment: 'node',
      encryptionScheme: {
        scheme: 'pkcs1_oaep', //scheme
        hash: 'md5', //hash using for scheme
      }
    }

var decryptKey = new NodeRSA(privateKey, 'pkcs1', options2);
decryptKey.setOptions(options2)
var decrypted = decryptKey.decrypt(encrypted, 'utf8');
console.log('decrypted: ', decrypted);
```

Result of running the above code.

```
f1zi49yKJSqkWW2J3Jt2lf1fe79JgqufFawYESOJRqhM4YEcGQBcaP39yptn7vShhsJBCTUOsbiV1YcW/YUzoaSQzX9YU0iTMara7h+LNLUrq4FZ2twy5X3uyAP1sUD1SnvQvlRJqrAh23UAwnx31rv6ySC+XgpLPR7wHYaDbSgyQKiF3qhGRj2SIAZ6weziNPfEm9FifBVjnWMvGDQYbjLbanbnSriN+bWpRtXKH9pQqMoskkiMwCviJdKtKzz/vVr0littPLnw0ojbsGSPKQPS3U3xCH3QiBmxEegc0uy3sJdk6aH/2SMuoPzGu7VS+PsLQctxnvKNnC9qsLFWyA==
true
decrypted:  This is the string to be encrypted using RSA!
```

Below is my code in JAVA

```
 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;


public class DecryptATT {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String encryptedData = "f1zi49yKJSqkWW2J3Jt2lf1fe79JgqufFawYESOJRqhM4YEcGQBcaP39yptn7vShhsJBCTUOsbiV1YcW/YUzoaSQzX9YU0iTMara7h+LNLUrq4FZ2twy5X3uyAP1sUD1SnvQvlRJqrAh23UAwnx31rv6ySC+XgpLPR7wHYaDbSgyQKiF3qhGRj2SIAZ6weziNPfEm9FifBVjnWMvGDQYbjLbanbnSriN+bWpRtXKH9pQqMoskkiMwCviJdKtKzz/vVr0littPLnw0ojbsGSPKQPS3U3xCH3QiBmxEegc0uy3sJdk6aH/2SMuoPzGu7VS+PsLQctxnvKNnC9qsLFWyA==";
//      Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPwithMD5andMGF1Padding");

        Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA1andMGF1Padding");

        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey();

        System.out.println("test");

        decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] original = decrypt.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedData));

        System.out.println(new String(original));

    }

    public static RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws Exception {
        String keyPath = "/Users/C.SubbiahVeluAngamuthu/Desktop/Samsung/Docs/att/Keys/3_my_testing/pkcs8_key";
        File privKeyFile = new File(keyPath);
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(privKeyFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new Exception("Could not locate keyfile at '" + keyPath + "'", e);
        }
        byte[] privKeyBytes = new byte[(int) privKeyFile.length()];
        bis.read(privKeyBytes);
        bis.close();
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        KeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes);
        RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(ks);
        return privKey;
    }


}
```

Below is the result of running the JAVA code

```
test
This is the string to be encrypted using RSA!
```

But when I change the cipher instance from `RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA1andMGF1Padding`  to `"RSA/ECB/OAEPwithMD5andMGF1Padding"`(which I am assuming is the one that I mentioned in encryptionScheme of node.js program) it throws the below error

```
test
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadOAEP(RSAPadding.java:499)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:293)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at DecryptATT.main(DecryptATT.java:26)
```

Could some one help me where it is going wrong ?

Comment: Using MD5 for signature generation is what's wrong, period. MD5 is broken, **do not use it**. Not even for MGF1.

Answer (score 4):

[RSAES-OAEP](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=16) is parametrized by

- the hash `Hash` used by OAEP, and its width in octet noted `hLen`
- the size of the public key, `k` octets
- the Mask Generation Function (MGF) used by OAEP

Almost invariably, the MGF is [MFG1](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=50), which itself is parametrized by the hash `Hash'` used by MFG1, and its width in octet noted `hLen'` (the `'` is not in the standard, I'm making up this notation).

You guessed it, there's noting stating that `Hash` and `Hash'` are the same, or even that  `hLen`= `hLen'`.

And, believe me, unless something special is done about it, under a typical Java environement `"RSA/ECB/OAEPwithMD5andMGF1Padding"` (if supported) will use MD5 for `Hash` but default to SHA-1 for `Hash'`; when perhaps node.js uses MD5 for both.

Facing a similar problem with SHA-256 rather than MD5, we can coerce the nice Java runtime to do the Right Thing with

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey, new OAEPParameterSpec(
    "SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT
));
```

I fear you won't be so lucky, since [MGF1ParameterSpec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/spec/MGF1ParameterSpec.html) seems to never have had an MD5 specifier; but perhaps give a try to `new MGF1ParameterSpec("MD5")` to get one before giving up.

If one really needs to get the job done under Java, one option is to roll one's RSAES-OAEP with MD5 on top of `Cipher` invoked with "RSA/ECB/NoPadding", which will perform textbook RSA, by far the most complex building block (at least, all the key management, modular arithmetic, and ability to offload to an HSM is taken care of). That's few dozens lines of code, including MFG1.

Another option might be [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/).

---

**It's a bad idea to keep using MD5**, even in MFG1. And it is an unmitigated disaster to use it as the main hash if adversaries can choose a part of the message at a time when they know what's before that part. If in doubt, **don't use MD5**.